# Jenkins docker: command not found

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have installed Jenkins on local machine (MAC OS) and docker as well.
I have created Jenkinsfile which contain below code

```
pipeline {
agent {
    docker { image 'python:2.7' }
}
stages {
    stage('Test') {
        steps {
            sh 'python --version'
        }
    }
}
```

}

Now clicked on Build Now which gave me an error like this

```
+ docker inspect -f . python:2.7
/Users/PKD/.jenkins/workspace/gfffffgfg@tmp/durable-42c1e897/script.sh: line 1: docker: 
command not found
[Pipeline] isUnix
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker pull python:2.7
/Users/PKD/.jenkins/workspace/gfffffgfg@tmp/durable-0ffec7d7/script.sh: line 1: docker: 
command not found
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 127
Finished: FAILURE
```

I'm new to Jenkins and trying to resolve this issue by google it but didn't find anything helpful.
Can someone please help me to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Have you installed docker?

Comment: Yes, i have installed in local machine which is running in virtual box.
docker --version
Docker version 19.03.3, build a872fc2

Answer (score 1):

The path to the `docker` binary is probably not in your `PATH` variable in the context that Jenkins is started in. Try executing docker by providing the full path to the executable, in my case it is: `/usr/local/bin/docker`. This will be the case if Jenkins is started by launchctl directly and doesn't pick up your bash or zsh envitonment.
If you've started Jenkins in a docker container however the reason for the docker executable not being found is different. You have no docker installed in your Jenkins container. But I doubt this is the case.